# Is it possible to publish same application for multiple Android SDK versions?

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application that has certain features available from API level 5 (Android SDK 2.0) onward. Application is fully functional without those features and they can easily be disabled.
Is it possible two publish two different versions of the application on the Market: one having target sdk 2.0 and greater and one having target sdk below 2.0?

Comment: See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) post and probably many duplicate questions on SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Yes, you can. [This is new](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html).

Alternatively, you can easily detect at runtime which version of Android you're running on, and enable/disable the extra features as appropriate.

Check the value of `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, for example.

Comment: I was looking for something like: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/multiple-apk-support-in-android-market.html
As you edited it your comment :) Thanx.